# Awk variable and summation

Tags: awk

I would like to understand the difference in result for the following awk commands.

I have read that when awk introduces numerical variables they are set to zero by default, so would assume that sum=0 would be implicitly assumed.

However 1) gives an incorrect result, while 2) is correct.

**Aim:** **Find the total number of lines in a file without using NR**

financial.txt

```
14D 20190503 0.31 0.31 0.295 0.295 117949
14DO 20190503 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.07 0
1AD 20190503 0.18 0.19 0.18 0.19 54370
1AG 20190503 0.041 0.042 0.041 0.042 284890
1AL 20190503 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.88 0
1ST 20190503 0.05 0.05 0.049 0.049 223215
3DP 20190503 0.049 0.054 0.048 0.048 2056379
3PL 20190503 1.055 1.06 1.02 1.05 120685
4CE 20190503 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.009 0
4DS 20190503 0.072 0.076 0.072 0.075 2375896

$ awk 'BEGIN {sum+=1} END {print sum}' financial.txt
```

1

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {sum=0}{sum+=1} END {print sum}' financial.txt
```

5527

Thanks

---

After reviewing comments, I found the solution I was looking for without using BEGIN.

```
$ awk '{sum+=1}END{print sum}' financial.txt
5527
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All awk variables are initialized to zero-or-null. If first used in a numeric context they become 0 at that point while if first used in a string context they become null at that point. Wrt your code samples, this:

```
BEGIN {sum+=1} END {print sum}
```

means:

```
BEGIN {sum+=1}
END {print sum}
```

while this:

```
BEGIN {sum=0}{sum+=1} END {print sum}
```

means:

```
BEGIN {sum=0}
<true> {sum+=1}
END {print sum}
```

See the difference? Add `;print sum` before every `}` to trace how `sum` is being populated if it's not obvious what's happening.

Comment: OK. In this case, what difference does {sum=0} make to the BEGIN statement? Does it act as a for loop to iterate through each record? – user just now    Edit

Comment: 1) With the BEGIN, for an empty file the `print sum` in the `END` section will print 0 instead of null. 2) What is "it" in that question?

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like BEGIN applies to the statement immediately following it, in this case sum=0 which ensures it is executed only once. {sum+=1} is not subject to the BEGIN statement so it executes per line.

Comment: I thought that BEGIN applied to the entire block of code before END.

Comment: awk is made up of `condition { action }` statements. `BEGIN` is a condition that is true before the first input file has been opened so the associated  `{ action }` is executed at that time, just like `END` is a condition that's true after the last input file has been closed and so ITS associated action would be executed at THAT time. It's all described in the man pages,

Answer (score 3):

From [GNU AWK Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGIN_002fEND) :

```
A BEGIN rule is executed once only, before the first input record is read. Likewise, an END rule is executed once only, after all the input is read.
```

Thus, the following will execute "{sum+=1}" statement only once.

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum+=1} END {print sum}' financial.txt
```

But, in 2nd case "{sum+=1}" is executed for every line read from the file.

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum=0}{sum+=1} END {print sum}' financial.txt
```